# how to add same dictionary to a list with modified value

Tags: python

```
csv={“a”:0}
list_=[]
for i in range(2):
    csv["a"]+=1
    list_.append(csv)
    print(list_,csv)
```

I am getting output like this:
[{'a': 2}, {'a': 2}]

I need to get an output like this
[{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because python pass variables to functions as reference and not as value, you need to pass a *copy* of the original dictionnary to `list_.append()`:

```
csv={"a":0}
list_=[]
for i in range(2):
    csv["a"]+=1
    list_.append(dict(csv))
print(list_)
```

Comment: What's the role of dict()

Comment: @JissRaphel The difference is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506043/9962106)

Comment: @JissRaphel Sorry I missread your question. `dict()` create a new dictionnary from the one you pass in parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a list-comprehension:

```
list_ = [{'a': x} for x in range(1, 3)]
# [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
```