# Clean way of passing parameters

Tags: c#

```
public EmployeeProcessOutput RetrieveEmployee(EmployeeProcessInput input)
{     
      var employee = input.Employee;
      if (input.EmployeeId == null)
          employee= CreateEmployee(employee);

      return new EmployeeProcessOutput
            {
                Employee = employee,
                State = "Stored" 
            };
}

private Employee CreateEmployee(employee)
{
      //Call a service to create an employee in the system using the employee 
      //info such as name, address etc and will generate an id and other 
      //employee info.
      var output = Service(employee)
      var employee = output.Employee;
      return employee;
 }
```

Is there a clean way and of passing the employee parameter to the `CreateEmployee` method. I feel that this line could be cleaner:

```
employee = CreateEmployee(employee);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: your code won't compile

Comment: You don't have to compile. Just need a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: wat you mean by clean? wat problems or inconsistency (you think) is there right now? btw, `CreateEmployee` signature seems to be perfectly okay.

Comment: @user1527762 until this code won't compile it not clear

Comment: This question makes no sense. Please rephrase it (your code isn't clear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about passing by reference instead of returning and assigning an Employee value? If so, you could do:

```
public EmployeeProcessOutput RetrieveEmployee(EmployeeProcessInput input)
{     
      var employee = input.Employee;
      if (input.EmployeeId == null)
          CreateEmployee(ref employee);

      return new EmployeeProcessOutput
            {
                Employee = employee,
                State = "Stored" 
            };
}

private void CreateEmployee(ref Employee employee)
{
      //Call a service to create an employee in the system using the employee 
      //info such as name, address etc and will generate an id and other 
      //employee info.
      var output = Service(employee)
      employee = output.Employee;
 }
```

Note that you must use the ref keyword because you are changing the value of the parameter itself.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708674/1730078) for more details.

That being said, this doesn't necessarily make the code "cleaner", and it is hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  But for some reason I get the impression this is what you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I would not say there was anything wrong with what you are already doing, but if you absolutely want to change and simplify that line, maybe you can use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?:

```
employee = employee.Create();
```

Which would call:

```
public static Employee Create(this employee)
{
    // ..call service, etc..

    return employee;
}
```

Note that this `Create()` method would need to reside in a separate public static class.