# How to access asp controls in a class file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a panel in my page view (tour.aspx file).
Now I want to access it in my class file (add_tour.cs file).

This is my panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="itinerary_panel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

This is my code behind `tour.aspx` file:

```
add_tour tour_obj = new add_tour();
int days_count = 2;
tour_obj.textbox_generator(days_count);
```

And this code is in `add_tour.cs` file:

```
public void textbox_generator(int days_count)
{

}
```

Now how to access the panel from aspx file?
Please help.

Comment: Your class should not touch the controls. The code behind should handle gathering values and passing them to other classes.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: What do you mean? I just told you what to do.

Comment: sir tell me in example so i can understand easily.

Comment: Why do you want a class other than the code behind touching your page anyways? What do you intend to do?

Comment: i don't know how to do

Comment: i want to access my asp:panel in my tour.cs class file

Comment: how can i access it?

Comment: I asked you what you want to do with it. That's important. What are you intending to do with this panel from your other class? If you don't give the full context of what you're after, it's unlikely you will receive a good answer.

Comment: i want to generate textbox in this panel

Comment: `txt_desc = new TextBox();
            txt_desc.ID = "txt_desc";
            itinerary_panel.Controls.Add(txt_desc);`

Comment: but i am using it lots of time so i want to create a method in my class file so i can access it when will i need that

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to actually add the text boxes to the panel from this class.

```
public List<TextBox> textbox_generator(int days_count)
{
    var textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

    for(int i = 0; i < days_count; i++)
    {
        txt_desc = new TextBox();
        txt_desc.ID = "txt_desc" + i.ToString();
        txt_desc.CssClass = "form-control";
        txt_desc.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter day " + i + " description");
        txt_desc.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        textBoxes.Add(txt_desc);          
    }

    return textBoxes;
}
```

Then change your code behind to:

```
add_tour tour_obj = new add_tour();
int days_count = 2;
var textBoxes = tour_obj.textbox_generator(days_count);
foreach(var textBox in textBoxes)
{
    itinerary_panel.Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

Note that you need to be careful where you add these controls in the page lifecycle. See [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx).

This keeps your `textbox_generator` from needing to know anything about the specific page using it.

Also, you should really align your naming conventions with C# standards. Use PascalCasing. `textbox_generator` should be `TextBoxGenerator` etc. And you can probably make `textbox_generator` into a static method if it doesn't need to access any fields or properties of its class.

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** wanted your other class to itself add the controls directly to the panel, then you would just pass a reference to the panel from the code behind to the class.

```
public void textbox_generator(int days_count, Panel panel)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < days_count; i++)
    {
        txt_desc = new TextBox();
        txt_desc.ID = "txt_desc" + i.ToString();
        txt_desc.CssClass = "form-control";
        txt_desc.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter day " + i + " description");
        txt_desc.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        panel.Controls.Add(txt_desc);          
    }
}
```

and call this this way from your code behind:

```
add_tour tour_obj = new add_tour();
int days_count = 2;
var textBoxes = tour_obj.textbox_generator(days_count, itinerary_panel);
```

This works because `itinerary_panel` actually is a reference to the panel. See [Passing Objects By Reference or Value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708632/passing-objects-by-reference-or-value-in-c-sharp). However, it's often a bad idea to have a method modify the state in that manner.

Comment: yes its working... and if i want to get the value from all those textboxs then what should i use? Ajax or Page_PreInit?

Comment: Can I ask why you're using web forms and not MVC?

Comment: because this is small scale of website application that's why i am making it with the use of web forms... there are only some dynamic pages.

Comment: @AjayChorge If you're just getting started, learn ASP.NET MVC. Don't waste your time with Web Forms. Web Forms will be going away, is slow, and is a terrible framework.

Comment: Thanks @mason  can you please suggest me some material which is available online? Which will helps me learn MVC Framework.

Comment: @AjayChorge I've found various videos to be helpful. See [these](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC) for ASP.NET MVC (watch them in order) and [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) for Dependency Injection.