# Type variable at function

Tags: c#

Good day!
This question seems easy, but I can't think out how to do it. I would pass Type parameter to function and check whether variable has that type.

```
void foo(Type type = ) // how to pass here default value for example System.Object?
{       
        if (elem.GetType() is type) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I have next classes

```
class Element {}
class ChildElementClass : Element {}
class SecondChildEleementClass : Element{}
```

And have array of Elements[], which is storing elements of all three classes

```
Element[] elements;
```

So, I would retrieve all elements for ChildElementClass. I make it by other way, but it is just interesting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708632/passing-objects-by-reference-or-value-in-c-sharp

Comment: Actually, this question seems like an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the underling problem that you try to solve?

Comment: Make the default `null` and check within the function to replace it with your actual default.

Comment: What re you trying to achieve ? Why do you need to have a default type ? I can't think of a time where this would make sense ... could be an XY problem

Comment: Btw: That's **not** how `is` works.

Comment: @ZoharPeled nothing especial, It is just interested for me.

Comment: I honestly don't think this is possible

Comment: @NikitaDayneko Why only this one? You can't do it with `object obj = new object()`, `DataTable table = new DataTable()`, etc. You can't initialize non compile-time constant parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
void foo(Type type = null)
{
    if (type == null)
        type = typeof(object);
}
```

See: [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JHR8TS)

Answer (score 2):

you could create a helper method to pass a default value

```
public void foo(){
   foo(typeof(object));
}
private void foo(Type type){
   //
}
```

or, set the default type as null and specify a default inside the method

```
if (type == null) {
    type = typeof(object);
}
```

Comment: How does your answer address OP's problem?

Comment: Good point, I'll adjust this so that it requires less thought