# Passing an object as a constructor parameter seems to be passing by reference instead of value

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm having strange issue where I am creating a new object which contains a parameter for another object (paramObj) I use through my function. So, paramObj is used in an object constructor, but it ends up being altered after the constructor is called. Since C# is pass by value, I'm not sure why this is happening.

My code:

```
void MyFunction(List<string> filesets)
{
    foreach(Fileset fs in filesets)
    {
        //At this point, fs.allFiles.Count is 30. The MyNewObject class
        //takes a Fileset as a parameters and eventually clears the 
        //Fileset.allFiles List, making the count 0.
        MyNewObject tmpObj = new MyNewObject(fs, null, "default");

        //At this point, fs.allFiles.Count is 0, but I expect it to be 30

    }
}
```

The `MyNewObject` class simply clears the `allFiles` list contained within a `Fileset` class. Why is that showing up after the constructor if C# is pass by value?

Comment: The reference `fs` is passed by value. Logically, the contents are passed by reference.

Comment: Are you saying all of the fields of a Fileset object are passed by reference - is that not the same as the entire object being passed by reference? Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Did you read that post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708632/passing-objects-by-reference-or-value-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you want to prevent the constructor from altering the object whose reference it receives, try the following: ``MyNewObject tmpObj = new MyNewObject((Fileset)fs.Copy(), null, "default");``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You´re right in that **everything in .NET is passed by value**. Even *references* - and this is what `fs` *actually* is - are passed by value. Thus, when you pass `fs` around your method will have a **copy of that reference**. This reference however references the exact same **object**, making any change on that reference modifiying the backing **object** also.

So in your constructor you have a **second reference** to the `FileSet`-instance **referenced** by `fs`.

This more or less leads to the conclusion, that objects are *effectivly* passed by *reference*.

There´s no simple way to circumvent this. It depends on why you even *modify* anything on that object within the constructor at all. You could try to copy the provided object referenced by `fs` within your constructor, e.g. by implementing `IClonable` within `FileSet` or by providing a copy-constructor within that class or whatever. However depending on what `FileSet` and it´s members are you will need some *deep* copy of the provided instance.

For further reading on how to make a deep copy of an object look here: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, all the objects are passed by reference as parameter to the method. On the other hand most of the primitive data types such as integer, double, Boolean etc. are passed by value.