# C# How to remove constantly updating items(data) from bindingSource

Tags: c#, multithreading, datasource

I'm using a datagridView, that it is bound to a `bindingsource`, 
this binding source is array of `List<MyClass>`.
 The `bindingsource` is constantly update from other threads(every 100 milliseconds).

```
* other threads can remove, add or update the bindingsource in any give time.
```

1) The `bindingsource.Remove(object)` method is not removing the object because the properties values are different, so there is no match for remove to work.

2) The `bindingsource.RemoveAt(int)` do remove the object, but is some case the wrong object because the `bindingsource` index is keep changing by other threads updates.

Can I remove an object from the `bindingsource` by property name? Or
how to remove the right object?

The below code is the non-working RemoveAt

```
        dataGridView_manage_positions.SuspendLayout();
        var position = GetPosition(uniqueID);
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _bindingSource_manage_grid.Count; i++)
        {
            var row = (MyClass)_bindingSource_manage_grid[i];
            // EXAMPLE: the row.Net = 1.52
            if (row.ID != position.ID)
                continue;

            dataGridView_manage_positions.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                 // this the problem. HERE i have a race condition 
                 // EXAMPLE: the row.Net = 2.56
                 // now the Remove() will not work, because the object value is different
                _bindingSource_manage_grid.Remove(row);
            }));

            break;
        }

            dataGridView_manage_positions.ResumeLayout();
```

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: You would be better off locating the correct instance of `MyClass` to be removed and then using `bindingsource.Remove(object)`

Comment: @Martin Parkin It doesn't work because the object  values are different in the time of the remove(). and I can't get the old values.

Comment: Hence find the correct _instance_ as I said.  It would never work when passing a different object because they are not the same.

Comment: just to clearly again: The object type is the same -> the inner values are not

Comment: This is not difficult.  Enumerate the objects in the data source and then find the one that you wish to remove and remove that instance of the object.

Comment: @Martin Parkin -> even then I will not work -> from the match point to the remove point the data can change

Comment: The datagridview is bound to a datasource containing your objects. There is no way it _cannot_ work if you remove one of the enumerated objects...

Comment: it possible i'm making the Remove() between the dataSource and the grid update(sync data) and this is why the Remove() is not working?

Comment: @Martin Parkin I updated the above code.. if you can look again it would be great :)

Comment: What is your condition for removing a row?

Comment: @Logan lets say I have 2 properties in my object. the first is a unique string and the second is int -> the Remove() need both properties values to match for a successful remove no?

Comment: @Universe68 no. The object itself is already unique. If you have an object of { a, b } and then change b's value, that does not change the object itself, because the object itself *references* other objects and values. UNLESS you have overridden `.Equals()` or `.GetHashCode()` in your object to use its members to check for equality.

Comment: @Logan It's not user based action. if I understand the question right

Comment: Ok let me ask this: is `row` a struct?

Comment: @Logon so I can override .Equals() or  .GetHashCode() to check that? the Remove() will use my methods?

Comment: @Logon on. It's Class with properties

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708632/passing-objects-by-reference-or-value-in-c-sharp