# core identity: AuthorizationPolicy named was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I want to add custom policies for two-step authorization, so after the first step user will have access to second step, and after that to everything. When I had one policy everything worked fine, but when I added another I started getting this error. How I add policies:

```
AuthorizationOptions authOptions = new AuthorizationOptions();

authOptions.AddPolicy("FirstStepCompleted", policy => policy.RequireClaim("FirstStepCompleted"));
authOptions.AddPolicy("Authorized", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Authorized"));

services.AddAuthorization(o => o = authOptions);
```

When I had one policy, I added it like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization
(
    options => options.AddPolicy("FirstStepCompleted",
    policy => policy.RequireClaim("FirstStepCompleted"))
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPD1. Forgot the exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'FirstStepCompleted' was not found.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicy.CombineAsync(IAuthorizationPolicyProvider policyProvider, IEnumerable authorizeData)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AddAuthorization` call takes a delegate that will receive an instance of `AuthorizationOptions` to configure. In your failing example, you are attempting to *replace* this existing instance of `AuthorizationOptions` with a new one that you've created above (`authOptions`), which has no real effect (see Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708674) for more information on reassigning parameters). Ultimately, this means *you're not adding any policies*.

If you want to add multiple policies in the delegate, you can use the following:

```
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    o.AddPolicy("FirstStepCompleted", policy => policy.RequireClaim("FirstStepCompleted"));
    o.AddPolicy("Authorized", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Authorized"));
});
```