# NSubstitute mock a void method without out/ref parameters

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I am trying to mock a void method without 'out' or 'ref' parameters and I am not able to mock it.
I want to modify parameter inside the mocked function

```
public interface IRandomNumberGenerator
{
    void NextBytes(byte[] buffer);
}

var randomImplementation = Substitute.For<IRandomNumberGenerator>();    
randomImplementation.When(x => x.NextBytes(Arg.Any<byte[]>())).Do(x =>
{
    x[0] = new byte[] {0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76};
});
```

But when I run this test got the **error:**

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.ArgumentIsNotOutOrRefException: 'Could not set
>   argument 0 (Byte[]) as it is not an out or ref argument.'

Is there any other possibility to change parameter inside void method ?

Comment: You seem to want to replace the entire array, which of course needs the param to be either ref or out. However you could try to replace the arrays **elements**.

Comment: How about turning `buffer` into an object (for instance, with a `bytes` array property) and access it like `buffer.bytes = new byte[]{...}` [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708674/9555272) how passing objects work in C#.

Comment: How would you **call** that code? Can you share the part where you call `NextBytes`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have two implementation one with Random.NextBytes() and second more secured for Encryption So calling such core is like that: 
var bytesArray = new byte[bytesize]; 
_randomNumberGenerator.NextBytes(bytesArray);

Comment: the problem is that whatever your generator actually does, unless `bytesArray` isn´t passed by ref the code that calls `NextBytes` won´t recognize it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **HimBromBeere** I catch what I was doing wrong.

So simply I can't pass filled byte array with new, i need to replace each item in array

```
public interface IRandomNumberGenerator
{
    void NextBytes(byte[] buffer);
}

var randomImplementation = Substitute.For<IRandomNumberGenerator>();    
randomImplementation.When(x => x.NextBytes(Arg.Any<byte[]>())).Do(x =>
{
    var byteArray = x.Arg<byte[]>();
    byteArray [0] = 0x4d;
    byteArray [1] = 0x65;
    byteArray [2] = 0x64;
    byteArray [3] = 0x76;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`x[0]` refers to the first argument passed to `NextBytes`, in your case the `buffer` parameter. As the parameter is not `ref` or `out`, changing the array reference within your mocked member won´t have any effect to the calling code. So effectively you're doing this:

```
class TheMoc : IRandomNumberGenerator
{
    public void NextBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        bytes = new byte[] {0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76};
    }
}
```

which of course won't be reflected in the calling code. This is why NSubsitute gives you the exception.

Having said this it's not really clear why you want this, as you're calling code will **never** reflect whatever your **actual** implementation of the interface does with that array.

So when your calling code looks like this:

```
theGenerator.NextBytes(bytes);
```

that code will still reference the "old" array, not the "new" one (which you try to mock away).

So you **will** need to provide the param as `ref` or `out` to reflect that modification in your calling code.

If you know that your array will allways have four elements you could just modifiy the arrays **content**, not its **reference**:

```
randomImplementation.When(x => x.NextBytes(Arg.Any<byte[]>())).Do(x =>
{
    x[0][0] = 0x4d;
    x[0][1] = 0x65;
    x[0][2] = 0x64;
    x[0][3] = 0x76;
});
```

So you do not want to match **any** call to `NextBytes`, but only those that provide an array with four bytes, making your `Arg.Any<byte[]()>` **effectivly** a `Arg.Is<byte[]>(x => x.Lengh == 4)`.