# Why object not act like reference type

Tags: c#, dictionary, object, reference-type

I have problem with dictionary, i write simple code to explain that, can i achieve `output` `2` instead of `1`?

I cannot use ref (because of TryGetValue)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object j = 1;
    Test(j);
    Console.WriteLine(j);
}

static void Test(object one)
{
    one = (object)2;
}
```

In my case i need to update dictionary row with key `name` with `myValue`

```
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out var outObject))
{
    outObject = myValue;
}
```

Comment: That's not how you update a dictionary, that's just to get the value. Use `dictionary[name] = myValue;` to set it.

Comment: Although you're boxing a `1`, you're passing the reference *by value*, so the original variable isn't modified.

Comment: @juharr but i dont want to double lookup for dictionary because of numbers of this operation its important for performance

Comment: dictionary lookups are not expensive.  Also this is only an issue if you only want to set it if the key is already there.  Otherwise `dictionary[name] = myValue;` will do an update if the key is there or add it if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

While you can pass an object to a method and modify, you *cannot* create a new object and have that be returned.

What you have is similar to this: [Passing Objects By Reference or Value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708632/passing-objects-by-reference-or-value-in-c-sharp)

When you do this:

```
one = (object)2;
```

you are assigning a new object to `one`, not modifying the original instance.  Since the original instance wasn't modified, you won't see the change outside that method.

Instead, what you can do is this:

```
static void Test(ref object one) // <---Note the "ref" key word
{
  one = (object)2;
}
```

This will allow you to return the object *by reference*.

Comment: I said that i cannot use `ref` because i nead it to `dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out var outObject)`

Comment: I see what you're getting at.  Give me a minute.

Comment: I think your best bet is what was proposed in comments: If you want to add the value if it doesn't exist: `dictionary[name] = myValue;`.  If you don't want to add a value, do `if (dictionary.ContainsKey(name)) dictionary[name] = myValue;`