# How can I update a reference returned from TryGetValue after its been inserted into a collection?

Tags: c#, dictionary, reference, ref, out

I have a dictionary inside a dictionary. I'd like to set a reference to the inner dictionary to a value *after* I'd added it to the outer dictionary as such:

```cs
var mammalIdSubscribers = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<Guid, int>>();
        
var mammalId = 0;
if (!mammalIdSubscribers.TryGetValue(mammalId, out var mammalSubscribers))
    mammalIdSubscribers[mammalId] = mammalSubscribers; // Add reference to inner dict to outer dict
        
Subscribe(ref mammalSubscribers);

/* 
mammalIdSubscribers[mammalId] is still null after the call 
to Subscribe despite mammalSubscribers being non-null. Why?
*/
        
static void Subscribe(ref Dictionary<Guid, int> subscribers)
{
    subscribers = new Dictionary<Guid, int> { { Guid.NewGuid(), 10 } };
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I'm not sure why (        `Console.WriteLine(mammalSubscribers.First().Value);` throws a null reference exception).

Can someone please explain why this doesn't work? In other words, why is `mammalIdSubscribers[0]` still `null` after the call to `Subscribe` with the `ref` keyword?

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't expose its contents to be accessed by reference, i.e. you cannot get a 
`ref` into one of its inner hashtable buckets. You can only do it on types that expose `public ref...` properties, and you must consume them with a `ref local`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref - Also see the docs for the `= ref` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator#ref-assignment

Comment: Where do you use the `Console.Log`method? are you sure `mammalSubscribers` is defined there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables, `mammalIdSubscribers` and `mammalSubscribers`, are *very similarly named*, so for the sake of clarity I'll rename `mammalIdSubscribers` to "`outerDict`" or maybe "[`biggerDict`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kx_G2a2hL6U)" while `mammalSubscribers` is renamed to "[`encarta`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkY-PxyaTuw)", because I used that *as a reference* a lot as a sprog.

[Line-by-line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWoW8L94oZY)...

1. `var biggerDict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<Guid, int>>();`

   - This gives us a valid, but empty, `biggerDict` dict.
2. `var mammalId = 0;`

   - Self-explanatory.
3. `biggerDict.TryGetValue(mammalId, out var encarta)`

   - This evaluates to `false`. The `out` param is also an inline `out` declaration, and when you use inline `out` declarations with `Dictionary`'s `TryGetValue` then the new variable will be `null` (or `default`) when it returns `false`.
   - ...and it will return `false` because `biggerDict` is empty, as established earlier.
   - ...therefore `encarta` is `null`.
   - (In case you blinked and missed it: **`encarta` is a new GC reference-type variable on the stack, it is *not* an alias or "reference" to any part of `biggerDict`**).
4. Because the `TryGetValue` call is inside an `if( !TryGetValue(...) )` statement it means that `biggerDict[mammalId] = encarta;` will be evaluated.

   - and `encarta` is still `null`.
   - ...therefore `biggerDict[mammalId]` (aka `biggerDict[0]`) is `null` .

- `Subscribe(ref encarta);`

  - This passes a reference to the local variable `encarta` to `Subscribe`.
  - **Crucially**, `encarta` is **not** a reference to any slot or space within `biggerDict`: it's still just a stack-allocated (aka *automatic*) object-reference-sized slot that's still `null`.

5. `encarta = new Dictionary<Guid, int> { { Guid.NewGuid(), 10 } };`

   - Inside `Subscribe`, at the machine-language level, a pointer(-ish) to the stack-allocated `encarta` local is deferenced and assigned to that `new Dictionary<Guid, int> { { Guid.NewGuid(), 10 } };`.
   - ...which means `encarta` is now **not `null`**.
   - Execution then returns to the previous function.
6. The `encarta` local is now a reference to that valid dictionary object on the GC heap. **But nothing ever invoked the `biggerDict[int].set_Item` property setter to make `biggerDict[0]` a non-`null` reference to the same object that `encarta` points to**.
7. Remember, excepting for *real* arrays (`T[]`), all other types with indexers are just sugar over property getter/setter methods, [which means object references are passed by value, and not references-passed-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708632/passing-objects-by-reference-or-value-in-c-sharp) - at least not without a `ref`-returning property, which `Dictionary<K,V>` does not do.